# Cannot push packages to azure artifacts feed, keeps asking for credentials

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, azure-artifacts

I have `.nupkg` files locally that I am trying to push to azure artifacts.
I've been pushing packages before but for some reason it now stops working.
I've got a feed setup and I got full owner privilege's to the feed in azure artifacts.

I've installed `NuGet.CommandLine` package to my project and I run the following command in the package manager console (the behaviour is duplicated when i run it from a windows command terminal)

```
nuget.exe push -ConfigFile "D:\Projects\myProj\NuGet.Config" -Source "Itm_Feed" -ApiKey az "D:\Projects\myProj\LocalPackages\ITM.VisiWin7.Common.2.12.0.nupkg" 
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '15.9.21.664' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\bin'.
Please provide credentials for: https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/tembogroup/HMI/_packaging/Itm_Feed/nuget/v3/index.json
```

Nuget.config

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>

  <!-- NuGet packages are now stored globally, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35809007/4122889 -->
  <!-- see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53451805/4122889 -->
  <config>
    <add key="globalPackagesFolder" value=".\Packages" />
    <add key="repositoryPath" value=".\Packages" />
  </config>
  
  <!-- Setup for local packages, not in a nuget source -->
  <packageSources>
    <add key="Itm_Feed" value="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/organization/team/_packaging/Itm_Feed/nuget/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>

</configuration>
```

As you can see it keeps prompting me for credentials - which it did not do before when it was working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> the behaviour is duplicated when i run it from a windows command terminal

I could reproduce this issue when I use the `Username and Password`.

To solve this issue, you could try to use **UserName** + [PAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page) (Personal Access Tokens).

For example:

[image]

On the other hand, if you need to enter the user name and password in the command line every time, it will be a little inconvenient.

So you could try to use the following command to add the [packageSourceCredentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file#packagesourcecredentials) to the nuget.config file.

Nuget Command:

```
nuget sources update -name Itm_Feed -username 123 -password <PAT>
```

In this case, you could run the Nuget Push without add Username and PAT.

[image]

**Note:** Nuget Resource name cannot be purely numeric.

Comment: Hm - too bad this just does not work out of the box like its described on azure artifacts (perhaps we need a little documentation there?). I've tried this way and it works however. Thanks for your efforts!

Comment: Hi @sommmen. Please check this doc:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/nuget/publish?view=azure-devops#publish-a-nuget-package-by-using-the-nuget-cli. It suggests that you could use username + PAT in Nuget CLI

Comment: If the answer could solve your issue, you may consider accepting it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: apologies, I meant the documentation page at https://dev.azure.com/tembogroup/HMI/_packaging?_a=connect&feed=Hmi_Feed It does not mention this possibility while it seems the 'this works most of the time' solution

Comment: Thanks. Microsoft just ruined my scripts with this change. Thanks Obama.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Developer command line caused this problem for me.  Creating a command prompt from Windows (not inside VS, i.e. not developer command line) works and I get a popup asking for credentials which allowed the package to be pushed